# Trivial GUI "update" question with Gtk4 and Python

Tags: python, gtk4

First of all - sorry. I know that this is very trivial, but I just can't wrap my head around this. Total newbie at GUI department.

But to the point: My very simple program calls another program that generates a jpeg file. My program then shows that picture. And by a push of a button I'd like to generate a new one and show it. But how do I update/refresh the GUI accordingly?

`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import time
gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class AppWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self, app):

        super(AppWindow, self).__init__(application=app)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        btn = Gtk.Button(label="Quit")
        btn.connect('clicked', lambda _: self.close())
        btn2 = Gtk.Button(label="Next pic")
        btn2.connect('clicked', lambda _: change_picture())

        #Run a function here, that generates 'initial_image.jpg'
        #before this it doesn't exist

        image = Gtk.Picture.new_for_filename('initial_image.jpg')
        
        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        grid.attach(image, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        grid.attach(btn, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        grid.attach(btn2, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        self.set_child(grid)
        self.set_default_size(800, 600)
        
def change_picture():
    # Run the function again that generates 'new_image.jpg' 
    # Before this it doesn't exist

    image = Gtk.Picture.new_for_filename('new_image.jpg')
    return image

def on_activate(app):

    win = AppWindow(app)
    win.present()

app = Gtk.Application(application_id='com.zetcode.Image')
app.connect('activate', on_activate)
app.run(None)
```

`

Tried to Google this to find examples, but couldn't find any simple ones to suit this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I'm getting the gist of it:

- My change_picture function is outside of the class
- I was not using "self".

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import time
gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class AppWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self, app):

        super(AppWindow, self).__init__(application=app)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        btn = Gtk.Button(label="Quit")
        btn.connect('clicked', lambda _: self.close())
        btn2 = Gtk.Button(label="Next pic")
        btn2.connect('clicked', lambda _: change_picture())

        #Run a function here, that generates 'initial_image.jpg'
        #before this it doesn't exist

        self.image = Gtk.Picture.new_for_filename('initial_image.jpg')
        
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.grid.attach(self.image, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        self.grid.attach(btn, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.grid.attach(btn2, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        self.set_child(self.grid)
        self.set_default_size(800, 600)
        
        def change_picture():
        # Run the function again that generates 'new_image.jpg' 
        # Before this it doesn't exist

            self.grid.remove(self.image)
            image = Gtk.Picture.new_for_filename('new_image.jpg')
            self.grid.attach(image, 0, 1, 2, 1)

def on_activate(app):

    win = AppWindow(app)
    win.present()

app = Gtk.Application(application_id='com.zetcode.Image')
app.connect('activate', on_activate)
app.run(None)
```